# Replace substring across Array of multiple data types in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, ijulia-notebook

I have an array imported from a csv of multiple datatypes.
I would like to remove all commas (,) and dollar signs ($). There are three columns with commas and dollar signs.

When creating a new array for a column with commas and dollar signs, I am able to do so successfully with below.

```
using CSV, DataFrames
df = DataFrame!(CSV.File("F:SampleFile.csv"))
dfmo = Array(df[!,30])
dfmo = collect(skipmissing(dfmo))
dfmo = replace.(dfmo,"\$"=>"")
dfmo = replace.(dfmo,","=>"")
```

When trying to apply across the entire vector with below

```
df=replace.(df,","=>"")
```

I get an error:

```
MethodError: no method matching similar(::Int64, ::Type{Any})
Closest candidates are:
  similar(!Matched::ZMQ.Message, ::Type{T}, !Matched::Tuple{Vararg{Int64,N}} where N) where T at C:\Users\
```

I then tried indexing with below and also get an error for indexing into a string.

```
for i in df
    for j in df
        if datatype(df[i,j]) == String
            df=replace(df[i,j],","=>"")
        end
    end
end
```

```
MethodError: no method matching similar(::Int64, ::Type{Any})
Closest candidates are:
  similar(!Matched::ZMQ.Message, ::Type{T}, !Matched::Tuple{Vararg{Int64,N}} where N) where T at C:\Users\
```

What is the most efficient way to replace substrings across an array of multiple datatypes?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your code I understand you want an in-place operation (i.e. to change the original data frame).

Using the loop approach as in your code you can do this:

```
for col in axes(df,2)
    for row in axes(df, 1)
        cell = df[row, col]
        if cell isa AbstractString
            df[row, col] = replace(cell, "," => "")
        end
    end
end
```

Using broadcasting you can achieve the same with:

```
helper_fun(cell) = cell isa AbstractString ? replace(cell, "," => "") : cell

df .= helper_fun.(df)
```